# Keyboard media key strokes impossible to capture?

Tags: macos, keycode

I'm trying to capture a keycode for a media keyboard for the keys "Calculator", "Email" and "Internet" on Mac OS X. But before that, I need to know the keycodes or key combinations that are used by these media keys.

Therefore, I've tried using the [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) software to capture the value but nothing happens (it doesn't capture anything).

I've also tried using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and it's EventViewer which works well for other media keys or function keys. Only the following three are troublesome: "Calculator", "Email" and "Internet". Each one of them is supposed to launch the corresponding default apps (Calculator, Mail, Safari).

The only other keys that cannot be captured are the ones which are already captured by the the OS like F4 for Launchpad. So I'm guessing that the previous three keys are already captured by the OS. The problem is, nothing happens when I press them and even if I use the `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts` and I try to assign some media key, nothing happens when all the other keys can be captured here (even F4 for example).

I'm starting to wonder if my keyboard really sends anything when I use these keys. I don't know what could capture the keycode before the System Preferences...

**EDIT**
To make it short:

- Where can I find keycodes for media keys (I've searched on Google and found only "normal" keys, nothing about media keys) - I've found some keycodes for [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) here, but that's all. Does it even exist for Mac OSX ?
- What could be capturing (and discarding) the media keys, preventing the OS of using them ? Or maybe OSX is completely ignoring them ?

**EDIT2**
I have found that Mac OS X has a program called "Remote Control Daemon" that captures the "Play/Pause" button and there are programs to disable it. But it doesn't change anything for the 3 media keys I'm having problems with.

I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right place to ask this question so thanks for moving the question if needed.

If you need more details, feel free to ask ! I'm really starting to go nuts ! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those keys are not standard. The OS X USB keyboard driver would need to support them, and it doesn’t.

There are different keyboards out there with those keys, and they don’t all generate the same codes. If yours is the Microsoft Internet Keyboard, there is an OS X driver for it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/internet-keyboard), but it’s old enough that it may not work any more (it says 10.4-10.7).

Comment: It's a Typematrix 2030

Comment: So basically you're telling me the problem is at the driver level?! Are you sure of that? Do you some source where I could learn more about this?

Comment: Well, the problem is that those keys aren’t standard, so it’s not clear what a generic OS-level driver is supposed to do to support those keys, since supporting them on one brand of keyboard might not support them on another brand. The OS X source code that maps USB scan codes is [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-503.215.2/IOHIDFamily/Cosmo_USB2ADB.c), but it’s hard to pinpoint exactly which DEADKEY entries would need to change because there are no standard USB scan codes for those keys. You can see the scan codes [here](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm).

Comment: Actually, according to [this page](http://www.typematrix.com/support/user-guide.php?item=12) if you put the keyboard in “106-key mode”, the email key generates 0x2b, which might be usable on OS X. The other two, not so much.